# Charger for a 32650 LIFEPO4 BATTERY PACK 4S2P 12.8V 10AH -12AH

Tags: battery-charging, lifepo4

Good day. I ordered a 4s2p LIFEPO4 battery online and it odes not come with a charger. I'm wondering what specific kind of charger do I need for this battery. Specs and the link of the battery are below.

Nominal Capacity：12.8v Type：Lifepo4 Voltage：14.6V

SPECS:

12.8V NOMINAL VOLTAGE 32650 LIFEPO4 CELL 3.2V 12000MAH / 12AH 4S2P CONFIGURATION 30A COMMON PORT BMS WITH BALANCING SHORTN CIRCUIT OVERCHARGE / OVERDISCHARGE PROTCTION

https://shopee.ph/32650-LIFEPO4-BATTERY-PACK-4S2P-12.8V-10AH-12AH-i.359763487.6282015737?sp_atk=3c1a42b5-bc70-4e60-af06-06c50d1399ed

Comment: 4S LFP chargers are so easy to find, there is no point trying to roll your own or misuse something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need a 4S LiFePO4 charger. Do not use a Lithium Ion / Lithium Polymer charger as they have completely different charge cycles and voltages.

There are many suitable chargers available, either as specialized LiFePO4 chargers, or as universal chargers with LiFePO4 settings.

The charge profile of 4S LiFePO4 batteries is very similar to that of 12V Sealed Lead Acid (car) batteries. They're often used as drop-in replacement for SLA. You can make do with a (modern) 3-stage SLA charger for charging LiFePO4's, as long as you do not exceed the maximum voltage or charging current for your 4S LiFePO4 battery and do not keep it on float/trickle charge. Using an SLA charger would be a compromise.

Ideally LiFePO4 batteries should be stored at around 50% SoC (storage charge) when they're not being used.

Comment: Thank you the response. Just to be sure, can I use the 14.6V(4S 12V3A) 3A LiFePO4 battery Charger?
Here's the link of the battery charger. https://shopee.ph/LiitoKala-58.4V-29.2V-14.6V-2A-3A-10A-LiFePO4-battery-Charger-48V-24V-12V-16S-8S-4S-i.16612090.12449016422?sp_atk=de144ad0-2dd1-43e8-bc80-862fc0b0323c
I would really appreciate your answer to this. :>

Comment: I think so, although I would not leave it on "float" for very long. There are some conflicting specifications on the page you linked to, so be sure to order the 4S (14.6V) LiFePO4 version.

Comment: Thank you, StarCat! I have already ordered the charger. I hope it would work just fine. will share a pic of it when it gets delivered :>